# Military strategy game on modern era

Tags: game

I'm looking for a game with *all* of the following features:

- strategy
- no fantasy, no sci-fi
- modern warfare (that is, post WW2)

and at least 1 of the following:

- runs on Linux (without wine)

or

- is somewhat popular: has streamers or lots of existing videos (regardless of age)

---

I spend daily a small amount of time playing games or watching streams, so why not combine it with learning (arguably) useful concepts.

For example, games like Age of Empires, Civilization, Empire Earth, taught me how insignificant the life of a soldier or villager is to a "successful" leader, and that destroying other nations to steal their resources is a very effective strategy (and used up to this day). Also taught me the effectiveness of focus-fire (that is, [concentration of force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_concentration)).

<sub>**Note**: I used to play [People's Generals](https://youtu.be/XL1JXSyYeG4?t=32m22s), an old turn based strategy game (>10 year old), hex map, with Patriot missiles, entrenched units, etc but it was Windows only. A game similar to this, with the above restrictions, would be great.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet would be the **Wargame** series according to their [steam pages](http://store.steampowered.com/sub/45320/) they should run on Linux, it is somewhat modern warfare (80s/90s) and the quality of the games looks fantastic, but this is a super hard core game, it might take some time/energy/online tutorials to get used to.

Review:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zh5dGGIQXn8

But here are a few others you can check out:

- [DEFCON](https://www.gog.com/game/defcon)
- [Red Alert 1 (with OpenRA)](http://www.openra.net/)
- [Jagged Alliance 2](https://www.gog.com/game/jagged_alliance_2) (with [Stracciatella](https://ja2-stracciatella.github.io/))
- [Door Kickers](http://store.steampowered.com/app/248610/Door_Kickers/)
- [Breach & Clear](http://store.steampowered.com/app/266130/Breach__Clear/)